# Lookup between two tables on a unique ID AND where the date is between two other dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables in Excel. One has Key and Date - this can be table A.  The other has Key, Begin Date, End Date, and Value - let's call this table B.

I am trying to pull into Table A the Value from Table B for the Key , where the Date from Table A is between the Begin Date and End Date from Table B.  The value should be 0.4 using the example tables below.

NOTE: There will never be overlapping dates and *shouldn't* have multiple rows for the same date range.

Table A -

```
| Key | Date       |
|-----|------------|
| 2   | 10/29/2018 |
```

Table B -

```
| Key | Begin Date | End Date   | Value |
|-----|------------|------------|-------|
| 1   | 07/01/2018 | 12/31/2999 | 0.1   |
| 1   | 01/01/1995 | 06/30/2018 | 1     |
| 1   | 01/01/1900 | 12/31/1994 | 0.5   |
| 2   | 10/31/2018 | 12/31/2999 | 3.6   |
| 2   | 01/01/1995 | 10/30/2018 | 0.4   |
| 2   | 01/01/1900 | 12/31/1994 | 10    |
| 3   | 01/01/1900 | 12/31/2999 | 100   |
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if there is more than one match? For example , key `2` and date `12/30/95` match both `0.4` and `10`.

Comment: IMO, create a helper column in both tables that is a concatenation of key and date, then perform a `VLOOKUP` off of those.

Comment: @BigBen Ahh I didn't read far enough into the question, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there'll only be one match, use `SUMIFS`.

```
=SUMIFS($I$1:$I$8,$F$1:$F$8,A2,$G$1:$G$8,"<="&B2,$H$1:$H$8,">="&B2)
```

[image]

Note - changed two instances of 12/31/1995 in Table B to 12/31/1994, assuming that it's a typo and date ranges shouldn't overlap between rows.

**EDIT:**

You can use `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` if you need to return text.

```
=INDEX(I2:I8,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$7)/(($F$2:$F$8=A2)*($G$2:$G$8<=B2)*($H$2:$H$8>=B2)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution - I was wondering what I'd do if I had to return a text value, though. I think a UDF would be the only solution.

Comment: Yeah hopefully we get clarification.

Comment: I think this is going to solve the issue I am having - you were absolutely right that I meant 1994 instead of 1995 in those couple of rows.  Still hoping someone comes back and answers what to do if we wanted to return a text value!